# php mysqli "No database selected" using class

Tags: php, mysql, class, mysqli

When I'm using mysqli without class it's going ok:

**index.php**

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php');

$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
$queryText = "SELECT * FROM User";
if($query = $mysqli->query($queryText)) {
    $results = $query->fetch_array();
    echo $results['userId'];
} else {
     echo "Error ";
     echo $mysqli->errno . " " . $this->mysqli->error;
}

?>
```

But when I start using mysqli with class something goes wrong. connectDB doesn't give any error, so i get connected to DB. But then when trying do any query it give me "No database selected error"
Result of index.php is: Error 1046 No database selected

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/banana.php');

$banana = new Banana(1);
if ($banana->connectDB()) {
    $banana->doQuery();
}
?>
```

**banana.php**

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php');

class Banana {

     private $mysqli, $userId, $query;

     function __construct($userId) {
          $this->userId = $userId;
     }

     function __destruct() {
        $this->mysqli->close();
     }

     public function connectDB() { // Подключение к БД
          $this->mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
          if ($this->mysqli->connect_errno) {
               echo "Error (" . $this->mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $this->mysqli->connect_error;
               return false;
          }
          return true;
     }

     public function doQuery() {
        $queryText = "SELECT * FROM User";
        if($this->query = $this->mysqli->query($queryText)) {
            $results = $query->fetch_array();
            echo $results['userId'];
        } else {
            echo "Error ";
            echo $this->mysqli->errno . " " . $this->mysqli->error;
        }
    }

?>
```

So it's very frustrating. I'm about 2 weeks in php, but can't find answer for couple days. I guess the answer is obvious but I can't see it.
Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: You should read up on variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Check your variables: `$results = $query->fetch_array();` - where is the '$this' ?

Comment: $mysqli is private property of class Banana. And everywhere in the class I using it as $this->mysqli.

Comment: You should not change your original question with the answers given as then the answers will not make sense any more.

Comment: @jeroen ok, i will not next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the first problems you will encounter when you run your script is here:

```
 public function connectDB() { // Подключение к БД
      $this->mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Note that all 4 variables you are using in your function call (`$hostname`, etc.) are undefined in the scope of the method.

There are several ways you can solve this:

- Pass the variables as parameters to the method:
  `public function connectDB($hostname, ...`
- Pass the necessary variable to your class constructor and set configuration properties in your class that you can use later on;
- Use constants instead of variables;
- Declare your variables global.

I would recommend one of the first 2 and definitely not the last one.

You can read more in the php manual about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Thanks, it helped.
Actually i did declared it global in config.php and imported it
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php');
And strange that $this->mysqli = new mysqli() didn't give me $this->mysqli->connect_errno

Comment: @TimurKhay The probably are global even without the global declaration in your config file. However, the method has no access to variables in the global scope unless you explicitly specify that in the method itself using the `global` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are a copy'n'paste victim.  In doQuery() change:

```
if($this->query = $this->mysqli->query($queryText)) {
        $results = $query->fetch_array();
```

To:

```
if($this->query = $this->mysqli->query($queryText)) {
        $results = $this->query->fetch_array();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did the change, but it didn't help. I guess I have raise error when I'm doing this
if($this->query = $this->mysqli->query($queryText))
because it goes to else block and echo "Error"

Comment: @TimurKhay And what is the error message?  Still the same `Error 1046 No database selected`?